# MVC: Controller often simply delegates to Model when notified by View of GUI events. Is this reasonable?

Tags: design, object-oriented, mvc

Since I learnt about MVC, I used it for every app I made (which is arguably not the best idea, but that's not the topic of this question). All of them small, 1000 LoC apps. I am using Java and Swing for the GUI.

What usually happens is this:

The view (the GUI class) reports to the controller about any GUI event (most commonly a button click) made. For example when a button is pressed, the view simply calls `controller.someButtonPressed()` or `controller.someOtherButtonPressed()`. It's only reaction to user input is reporting to the controller, nothing else.

This, I think, is fine and is proper MVC View implementation. The part I'm having doubts about is the following:

In the controller's `someButtonPressed()` methods, it very often simply delegates to the model.

For example:

```
public void someButtonPressed(){
    model.doTheAppropriateThing();
}
```

Nothing more. No 'decision making' or actual 'interpretation' of what the view reported. Very often, only simple delegation to the model.

**Is it considered reasonable when implementing MVC structures and specifically controllers, to have the controller often simply delegate directly to the model in reaction to GUI events?** Or does this signal that maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, your model code would be in a separate DLL / Shared Library / Jar file / re-usable module,  and could be included in a system that handles API requests from any client, whether that be an Android App speaking a socket-level protocol or a web page speaking HTTP or some freaky combination of something else.

In those cases, IMHO, the Controller is responsible for making the data that belongs in the View (the app, the web page) appropriately transformed for the view, but also takes care of error handling (HTTP status codes perhaps in one case, and some custom format in another case).

Essentially controllers *mediate between models and views*,  which means they might need logic that deals with that mediation (data transformation, creating DTOs, returned error information in the appropriate way).  But the logic of what it *means* in the system when a user takes some action, is the responsibility of the model. The model is the view-and-controller-agnostic representation of the domain. The controller mediates between.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Not sure if I understand your answer, but I'm not sure it answers exactly the question. I know what the job of the controller is, and that it's supposed to mediate between the model and the view. My question was if it's reasonable that often the controller mediates simply by delegating directly to the appropriate method on the model, when the view reports about a user action. Do you have an opinion regarding this?

Comment: In theory, it's possible.  I don't know if it would be a good idea, but in theory it's possible.  Edit:  in theory it's not incorrect. If you didn't care about the return value of the function and various other things were already taken care of... but this is actually almost a code-smell to me, because it probably means that the code base suffers from low cohesion, and IMHO high cohesion is very important and perhaps more important than many other more popular principles.

Comment: I edited to point out that the model should be view AND controller agnostic.

Comment: I'll describe an example situation, please say if it seems to you like a correct MVC implementation: consider a word processor. The user clicks the `Bold` button on the GUI (the view) to make text bold. In reaction, the view calls `controller.boldButtonClicked()`. In the `boldButtonClicked()` method, the controller simply calls `model.makeTextBold()`. The model then carries out the logic needed to make text bold, and updates the view. Does this seem reasonable? The part where the controller simply delegates to the model?

Comment: It's going to be much, more complex than that fundamentally in your example. For example in the context of a word processor, the Controller layer probably has to do things like find out which characters in the document are highlighted and let the model know that.

Comment: Fundamentally the hardest part of development is understanding what your abstractions should be. The best advice I can give is, the model is the thing that doesn't change no matter what the application is and is therefore the most reusable part of the system. It contains both data and behaviour. In MVC the view is also very reusable. A text box is usable in many different applications and contexts. The controller is the least re-usable since it has to have intimate knowledge of the context.

Comment: These are ideas very tightly coupled to the conventional desktop application-centric notion of MVC. Things can be different on the Web and things can be different in client-server applications, where the MVC pattern may not directly apply. In that case you need to either figure out something that works for you or look at other patterns that might be better suited. Also keep in mind that MVC is often considered to be a compound design pattern.

Comment: Bottom line is that the three concepts in MVC have become so overwrought that I'm not sure that they really mean anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine if you have methods like the `someButtonPressed()` in your example. It is important though, that you only have to change the controler but not the model *if* the logics when pressing `someButton` changes somewhen in the future. Also the other way around: if the models `doTheAppropriateThing()` method changes then you don't have to care for the view.

The result is that your view and model are decoupled and when the controller is only "passing" the method calls that's fine.